# How to return a multidimensional array of numbers in descending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JS and I am tring to sort a multidimensional array and I want to return the array in descending order -

Input -

```
let input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

Expected Ouput

```
[[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,3,1],[2,1,3],[1,3,2],[1,2,3]]
```

I have tried sort

```
let result = input.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

But I am getting the same array sent back to me

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

I have also tried a for loop with the sort method

```
for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  let inputArr = input[i]
  let output = inputArr.sort((a,b) => a - b)

  console.log(output)
}
```

But I get returned

```
[1,2,3] 6 times (the length of the original array?)
```

How do I return the array values in descending order?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the subarray items against each other - `.sort((a, b) -> a - b)` makes no sense because `a` and `b` are arrays, and so can't be meaningfully subtracted from each other.

```js
let input = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]];
input.sort((a, b) => {
  // Find the first index that's different between the two subarrays being compared
  const diffIndex = a.findIndex((itemA, i) => b[i] !== itemA);
   // Return the difference, so that the higher value will come first in the result
   // If no difference found, return 0 (so they will come next to each other)
  return diffIndex === -1 ? 0 : b[diffIndex] - a[diffIndex];
});
console.log(input);
```

That's assuming that the subarrays contain the same number of values, as it is in the example.

Comment: Good answer, but it would be nice if you commented that to make it understandable to the OP. I doubt that a JS newbie could make head or tail of that.

Comment: @seesharper yes please would definatley help as I am finding this answer hard to understand thanks

Comment: @ubermo See the comments in the answer. You first find the first index that's different between the subarrays being compared - eg `[1, 2, 3]` against `[1, 2, 4]` will give index 2 (because indices 0 (value 1) and 1 (value 2) are the same for both. Then by subtracting the difference of the values between the first different index, you get the relative order in the sorted array.

Comment: @ubermo, consider that in order to order two arrays, the sort function needs a result that will be positive if a should come before b, negative if the other way round, and 0 if the two are equal. In terms of sorting, it's only the first differing number that matters for the sort (the ones that come after that number can be ignored since they have less "weight"). So this function finds that first differing number and then returns a-b to give the sort order of the two arrays being compared.

Answer (score 0):

The sort operation expects numbers. You can apply the `.sort()` array method on `input` using concatenated inner array elements converted into a number - `+arr.join('')` - as in the following demo:

```js
let input = [ [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [3,2,1], [3,1,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1] ];

const sorted = input.sort( (a,b) => +b.join('') - +a.join('') );

console.log( sorted );
//OUTPUT: [ [3,2,1], [3,1,2], [2,3,1], [2,1,3], [1,3,2], [1,2,3] ]
```

**NOTE**

You may also use `parseInt( arr.join('') )` in place of `+arr.join('')`.